# erc-mode : how to hide alerts when users join/leave a channel

Tags: erc

I just began using erc-mode and I noticed that erc-mode alerts whenever people join or leave a channel. Is there a way I can somehow hide the alerts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(setq erc-hide-list '("JOIN" "PART" "QUIT"))

You can use `describe-variable` if you are looking for variables. It's very convenient when you want to change a certain behaviour and you don't the variables's name.